# Passing sting of characters as single command line argument

Tags: powershell, parsing, command-line

This is test script for test.ps1:

```
$V1=$args[0]
$V2=$args[1]
$V3=$args[3]
Write-Output $V1 $V2 $V3
```

I am invoking following: powershell test.ps1 A B "This is a test"

**Output is**
A
B
This

**What I want is:**
A
B
This is a test

I need "This is a test" to be read in as a single value...

Comment: Well, first off you are wanting 3 parameters but the code you posted is trying to access a fourth one.

Comment: powershell A B "'This is a test'"

Comment: https://rcmtech.wordpress.com/2013/08/23/powershell-and-double-quotes-on-the-command-line/

Comment: PowerShell already does what you ask. Why are you skipping `$args[2]`? And why do you need `$args` in the first place? Named parameter parsing is built into PowerShell.

Comment: I suspect that this is a not really accurate representation of some other code that is actually being run.

Comment: If that's correct, then this question should be rewritten or deleted. It seems nonsensical as currently written.

Answer (score 0):

Please use single quotes to take it as raw string rather than an escaped string.

```
old: powershell test.ps1 A B "This is a test"
new: powershell test.ps1 A B 'This is a test'
```

Comment: Single vs. double quotes makes no difference in this example. Read `help about_Quoting_Rules` for details.

Comment: Single quotes inside of double quotes work though :)